# Ignore case in email address used in a form

Tags: php, email, email-validation, lowercase

For users that forget their login credentials I have a form they can fill out that includes their email address. It is compared to a list of email addresses that is all in lower case.

Can I.. have the case of the email address ignored if the user uses caps?

I recently used strtolower() to ignore the case of my login which worked great but am having troubles trying to implement the same in my form.

Thank you for any advice or help.

```
   <form action="../pages/send_mail.php" method="post">
<table width="470" border="0" cellpadding="3">
 <tr>

<td height="117" colspan="3"><left>
<font size="+2"><b>Please type in your email address as listed in the Shareholders list</b>
<span style="color:red; font-size: 125%; font-weight: bold;">
</span></center></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
    <td width="250"><b>Email address&nbsp; &nbsp; &gt;&gt;&gt;</b></td>
    <td width="300"><input type="text" name="email_address" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><b></b>&nbsp;<br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Click this bar to have an email sent to the address above with your username and password " style="font-size:11px;" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `strtolower($_POST['email_address'])` just lowercase it then. `troubles trying to implement the same [lowercase] in my form. ` < please explain.  You can use javascript to do the same on the client side.  `$('input[name="email_address"]').toLower();` Normalization is the word here.

Comment: ^ ``$('input[name="email_address"]').val().toLowerCase();`` do this on blur of the field, if it's a client side issue, or before you use the value in JS (jQuery)

Comment: Thank you but left confused. Are you saying this code strtolower($_POST['email_address']) will do the trick and if so, where do I place it in "my code"

Comment: you haven't shown any code only HTML ( which is a markup language ), if you want to change it in the html it may be possible with just css, but I am not sure of the browser support for it. see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp  `<input type="text" name="email_address" style="text-transform: lowercase;" />` may work.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.. and point out that I am showing only HTML code. Thus my problem with trying to add PHP.... Your suggested HTML code incidentally does not work at least with FireFox but at least it did not crash the page as my other attempts adding PHP did.